# How do I call a React re-render when the Array is being updated outside the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've built a Chat-App where the Chat is being updated in a different file. The Chat is saved as an Array.

For now you could say that I've cheated a bit, with updating the component every 500ms.
I know its not encouraged to use this.forceupdate().

```
 class MessageDisplay extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {record :false};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    send.sendMessageToServer("helloQuickreply");
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const element = document.getElementById("scrollToMe");
    element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
  }

  tick() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.forceUpdate();
    }, 500);
    return (
      <div className="chatBox">
        <ui.showMessage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The Dream would be to only force an update when the user sends or receives a message.
So how can you call an this.forceupdate() in another file?

This is send.js
It would be beautiful to call it here somewhere

```
export function sendMessage(text) {
  fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", 
    async: true,
    body: JSON.stringify({ text:text}), 
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .catch(error => console.error("Error:", error))
    .then(response => {

      save_response_in_ChatArray()
      //Call Forceupdate somehow?
    });
}
```

The array is being shown like so:
showMessage() is also being called in another file.

```
export function showMessage() {

  let listItems = messageList.map(d => (
    <div>
      <p className={d.senderId + "timestamp"}>{d.time}</p>
      <p className={d.senderId} key={d.idCount} ref={d.idCount}>
        {" "}
        {d.text}{" "}
      </p>
    </div>
  ));
```

Comment: How is the array getting into MessageDisplay? Are you passing it as a prop?

Comment: I updated the Question a bit.
Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Nicholas asked you good question. We cannot see this from your code and it is a crucial thing for solution of your problem.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: True, I hope I added some crucial extra Infos.
I will update.